# Convert curl sample to c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, curl

How would you go about writing this CURL sample in c#:

```
curl -u d4a581cceff06c03a47015643661ee75:x https://sample.crm.com/api/users
```

Comment: Definitely check the linked question, above. The `-u` is specifying the user name and password, which you'll need to set in the `Credentials` of the `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: The thing is I only have a token, no username or password. So Credentials wants both.

Comment: Looks to me like the password there is `x`.